# How to use expr on float?

Tags: bash, floating-point, rounding, fixed-point

I know it's really stupid question, but I don't know how to do this in bash:

```
20 / 30 * 100
```

It should be `66.67` but expr is saying `0`, because it doesn't support float.
What command in Linux can replace expr and do this equalation?

Comment: Sorry, mea culpa, mea maxima!

Comment: for maths operations, try to use bc or awk , not bash or expr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As reported in the bash man page:

> The shell allows arithmetic expressions to be evaluated, under certain circumstances...Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with no check for overflow, though division by 0 is trapped and flagged as an error.

You can multiply by 100 earlier to get a better, partial result:

```
let j=20*100/30
echo $j
```

66

Or by a higher multiple of 10, and imagine the decimal place where it belongs:

```
let j=20*10000/30
echo $j
```

66666

Comment: It might help if you posted the actual command line you used.  (I'm guessing you used more zeroes than I did.)  I executed the commands above before I posted, and got the results given.  Please try those first.

Comment: Huh, odd, I don't remember putting spaces in there originally.  Anyhow, try removing your spaces and repeat.  I edited my post to remove the problematic whitespace.

Comment: The question was to deal with floating point number; bash "let" returns integer

Comment: Yes, HidekiAI, that's why I say to "imagine the decimal place where it belongs".  The returned result 66666 represents an actual value of 66666 * 10^-3.

Answer (score 39):

`bc` will do this for you,  but the order is important.

```
> echo "scale = 2; 20 * 100 / 30" | bc
66.66
> echo "scale = 2; 20 / 30 * 100" | bc
66.00
```

or, for your specific case:

```
> export ach_gs=2
> export ach_gs_max=3
> x=$(echo "scale = 2; $ach_gs * 100 / $ach_gs_max" | bc)
> echo $x
66.66
```

Whatever method you choose, this is ripe for inclusion as a function to make your life easier:

```
#!/bin/bash
function pct () {
    echo "scale = $3; $1 * 100 / $2" | bc
}

x=$(pct 2 3 2) ; echo $x # gives 66.66
x=$(pct 1 6 0) ; echo $x # gives 16
```

Comment: but i want to do this in script, the full line is :
$ach_gs / $ach_gs_max * 100

Comment: @maxorq: You might note that in all examples others have given, the multiplication is done first.  This is a scientific computing thing -- since we know there are more digits available to the left of the decimal place than to the right, multiplication goes first to minimize loss of precision due to rounding.

Answer (score 17):

just do it in awk

```
# awk 'BEGIN{print 20 / 30 * 100}'
66.6667
```

save it to variable

```
# result=$(awk 'BEGIN{print 20 / 30 * 100}')
# echo $result
66.6667
```

Comment: This answer is very awkward.

Comment: Good answer. There's a bigger change a system has awk than bc.

Answer (score 15):

I generally use perl:

```
perl -e 'print 10 / 3'
```

Comment: it must be a very basic perl issue, but this command only displays a blank line on my system. `perl -e 'print "hello world"'` does not work either. But `perl -e 'print "hello world\n"'` does work as expected.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help. All I can suggest is to add `, "\n"` to the end of the expression: `perl -e 'print 10 / 3, "\n"'`

Comment: Thanks, this workaround works. (and your command works 'as-is' on another linux environment)

Comment: For the Pythonistas among us: `python -c "print 10.0/3.0"`

Answer (score 5):

```
> echo "20 / 30 * 100" | bc -l
66.66666666666666666600
```

This is a simplification of the answer by paxdiablo.  The -l sets the scale (number of digits after the decimal) to 20.  It also loads a math library with trig functions and other things.

Answer (score 0):

Another obvious option:

```sh
python -c "print(20 / 30 * 100)"
```

assuming you are using Python 3. Otherwise, use `python3`.