# Bash Math Oddity (Floating Point Division)

Tags: bash, math, bc, expr

So I'm having some trouble with bash / bc math here..

I'm trying to print the filesize in of a backup after I move it to my gdrive via rclone for backup. So I get the filesize via an rclone ls statement with awk print $1 which works great.

In my specific example, I get the value of 1993211 (bytes).

So in my printing code I try to divide this by 1048576 to get it into mb. Which should give me 1.9 mb.

However,
 `$ expr 1993211 / 1048576 | bc -l`

prints `1`

I've tried various other math options listed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks) (incl via python / node) and I always get 1 or 1.0. How is this possible?

The calculation should be `1993211 / 1048576 = 1.90087413788`

Any idea whats going on here?

Comment: This question may be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253987/how-to-use-expr-on-float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it does integer division.
Do get floating point division you could run:

```
bc -l <<< '1993211 / 1048576'
```

which returns: 1.90087413787841796875

or you can set the number of decimals using scale:

```
bc -l <<< 'scale=5; 1993211 / 1048576'
```

which returns: 1.90087

Answer (score 2):

In the command `expr 1993211 / 1048576 | bc -l`, `expr` divides 1993211 by 1048576 using integer division ('cause that's what `expr` knows how to do), gets "1" as the result, and prints it. `bc -l` receives that "1" as input, and since there's no operation specified (`expr` already did that), it just prints it.

What you want is to pass the expression "1993211 / 1048576" directly as input to `bc -l`:

```
$ echo "1993211 / 1048576" | bc -l
1.90087413787841796875
```